# wait() returns 0 and errno = "Interrupted system call"

Tags: c++, process, wait, system-calls, waitpid

I'm doing a school assignment that basically involves creating a couple of child processes which approximate `pi` and write their results to a text file with the same name as the child process id. The parent process then waits for all the children and calculates the average approximation for `pi` from the values stored in the text files.

Things work pretty good, but every now and then (about 10% of the times I execute the program) `wait(NULL)` returns -1 and `errno` indicates `Interrupted system call` for one of the child processes. I have no idea why this happens seemingly randomly.

In the code below, `MonteCarlo` is a custom class that deals with the approximation of Pi.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "MonteCarlo.h"


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int approximationProcessCount = 10;
    int approximationRandomCount = 1000;


    for(int i=0; i<approximationProcessCount; i++){
        //pidArray[i] = fork();
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if( pid == -1 ){
            // Fork error
            perror("Fork error");
        }
        else if( pid == 0 ){
            // Child process
            MonteCarlo mc(approximationRandomCount);
            std::string filename(std::to_string(getpid()) + ".txt");
            std::ofstream fs( filename );

            if( !fs ){
                std::cerr << "Cannot open '" << filename << "' for writing." << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            fs << mc.approximate();
            fs.flush();
            fs.close();
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            // Parent process
        }
    }

    // Parent process
    double averageApproximation = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i<approximationProcessCount; i++){
        pid_t childPid = wait(NULL);

        if( childPid == -1 ){
            perror( std::string("Error when waiting for child process [-1] (i=" + std::to_string(i) + ")").c_str());
            continue;
        }
        else if( childPid == 0 ){
            perror( std::string("Error when waiting for child process [0] (i=" + std::to_string(i) + ")").c_str());
            continue;
        }

        std::string filename(std::to_string(childPid) + ".txt");
        std::ifstream fs( filename );

        if( !fs ){
            std::cerr << "Cannot open '" << filename << "' for reading." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        double approximation;
        fs >> approximation;
        fs.close();
        remove(filename.c_str());

        // Calculate average "on the fly"
        averageApproximation += (approximation - averageApproximation)/(i+1);
    }

    std::cout << "Average approximation of Pi = " << averageApproximation << std::endl;

}
```

When I encounter the "error", I get the following output (`i` varies):

```
Error when waiting for child process [-1] (i=9): Interrupted system call
Average approximation of Pi = 3.14444
```

I'm running this in XCode on Mac OSx El Capitan.

Comment: have you checked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160583/fork-multiple-processes-and-system-calls

Comment: That's a pretty poor dupe, @molbdnilo.

Comment: The value of `errno` is irrelevant unless the immediately prior system call has returned -1. Your `perror()` call is invalid.

Comment: The answer linked to by @Hayt solved my problem, the duplicate just made me more confused...